# Can the new Azure File Service be used from Azure WebSites?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

The title pretty much says it all...
Microsoft just launched the new File Services on Azure.
(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx)
Can I use it from within a Azure WebSite?
Or is it limited to use from VMs and CloudServices due to "net use" restrictions?
Thanks

Comment: Were you able to use File Service with an Azure Website via SMB?  I am also very much interested in this possibility.

Comment: Nope. It seems SMB access is not possible from WebSites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - use the REST API - the Azure website MUST be in the same region as the storage account.

> Once your share is created, it can be accessed via the SMB or REST
>   protocol from any Azure node (VM/Worker/Web role) hosted in the same
>   region as the storage account hosting the share.

Comment: I believe the same region limitation only applies if you're mounting it as a native SMB share. If you're using the REST api, can you access from anywhere.

Comment: REST is not enough for what I want to do.
I am looking for a way to access via SMB.
Basically I want to migrate some content (user-uploaded pictures for a social site) to a path outside D:\home\site\wwwroot, for persistence and easier sharing with other services.
The existing code only allows access to "normal" paths, not REST based access.
Thanks

Comment: The Azure website doesn't have to be in the same region. What @BrentDaCodeMonkey said is absolutely correct. The preview-documentation is accessible here: [File Service REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn167006.aspx) and the corresponding Azure-Team blog-post here:[Introducing Microsoft Azure File Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx)

Comment: @awsomedevsigner  OK, so I just want to make sure I am understanding this correctly... does this mean you CAN use the SMB protocol from a Windows Azure Website?